# Why do they get to be happy?

Tags: riddle

> Everyone like me is happy.
>
> But I never am.
>
> Well, except in England.

(First post here, hope it's not too obscure!)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you

> Christmas

?

Everyone like you would be

> Other holidays: Happy New Year, Happy Hallowe'en, Happy Birthday, Happy Independence Day (in whatever country)

But you never are

> Merry Christmas is more common

Except in England

> where they do say Happy Christmas quite regularly

A minor quibble, not "everyone like you" fits this, eg

> Happy Yom Kippur is somewhere between funny and a faux-pas. There may be others.

Comment: Well done! I was afraid it was too little information!

Answer (score 8):

You're

> **Happy**, the dwarf.

Everyone like me is happy

> Because you're happy all the time.

But I never am. Well, except in England.

> You're Happy in England, but in other countries you have other names.

Comment: I think this would still hold true in other English speaking countries. The mention of England seems very specific here.

Comment: Interesting answer! It's not the one I had in mind, though - I have no reason to believe that Happy isn't happy.

Answer (score 8):

Given the specific reference to England I think the answer might be

> Mondays

Everyone like me is happy.
But I never am.

> "Everyone like me" here refers to the other days of the week which are generally relatively "happier" than Mondays as Mondays represent the start of the working or school week for a lot of people.

Well, except in England.

> In England, they have the band [Happy Mondays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Mondays) so this would be the possible specific exception (relating Mondays to the word "happy").

Comment: Also an interesting answer! But I've never heard of Happy Mondays, and know very little about England in general. The riddle doesn't require England-specific knowledge to that level.

Answer (score 5):

Might it be

> the game 'We Happy Few'

Everyone like me is happy.

> They take a drug called 'Joy' which takes away bad memories and only leaves the good ones

But I never am.

> The main character (you) stopped taking the drugs and sees the world as it is. Because you stop taking the drug you are no longer happy like the others.

Well, except in England.

> The game plays itself in an alternate version of England in which Germany has taken over.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it the minion "kevin" from the movie Minions? Because he wanted to travel and then finally does and meets the main "villain" Gru?

Comment: could you emphasize on **the minion**

Comment: Ive done what i think you wanted

Comment: Hahaha, very creative! Is Gru in England though? I don't remember the movies well enough to see your logic.

Answer (score 2):

Going out on a limb here...

> Present

Everyone like me is happy.
But I never am.

> People speak of the good old days, or the bright future, but the present always sucks.

Well, except in England.

> Present, as a word meaning gift, is 4 times more commonly used in UK English than other English variants. And presents do make people happy.

Comment: "Present" in that sense is still very common in AmE.  Can't speak for Canadians, Aussies, etc., but I'm pretty sure that meaning is widely understood in all flavors of English.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I do agree, but it is FAR more common in the UK. I did express I was on a limb. I guess it snapped.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is it, but maybe?

You are:

> A clam

Everyone like me is happy.

> The phrase "happy as a clam" is pretty common.

But I never am.

> Are clams actually happy?  Do they even have the mental capacity for joy?  Can we ever even know?

Well, except in England.

> Well, there's [this popular restaurant](https://www.facebook.com/TheHappyClamPubandEatery/) in Maine, so that's at least in *New* England...